Conjugacy in the alternating group
I was studying group theory when a question came to my mind.
Given a natural number n, let's call S and A respectively the symmetric and the alternating groups on n elements. It is known that S is ambivalent, i.e. that every elements of S is S-conjugate with its inverse. The latter may not happen in A.
I have the following question. If an element of A is A-conjugate with its inverse, is it true that its A-conjugation class is equal to its S-conjugation class?
It is known in general that every S-conjugation class may split in at most two A-conjugation classes, so basically I wonder if it is possible for an S-class to split but maintaining an element and its inverse in the same A-class.

Have you looked at the conditions for when a class of conjugates splits (there's an explicit condition)?  Do you know how conjugation changes the cycles in a cycle decomposition?

@MichaelBurr No and yes respectively.

You may be overusing that opening line of yours. It's starting to sound as a mindless way to avoid giving context.

@ArturoMagidin This is your opinion, while the opening line is exactly how it goes. The essential context is provided immediately after it, for those who go further.

Try $(1,2,3,4,5) \in A_5$.

It happens for example for $n=5$ and the classes of 5-cycles.

The $S_n$-class of $\sigma\in A_n$ splits if and only if the decomposition of $\sigma$ into disjoint cycles has no cycles of even length and all its cycles are of pairwise distinct lengths. E.g. here.
In particular, if $n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, $n\geq 5$, and $\sigma$ is a cycle of length $n$,
$$\sigma = (a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{4k+1}),$$
then its $S_n$-conjugacy class splits in $A_n$. And
$$\sigma^{-1} = (a_1,a_{4k+1},a_{4k},\ldots,a_2) = \rho\sigma\rho^{-1},$$
where
$$\rho = (a_2,a_{4k+1})(a_3,a_{4k})\cdots (a_{2k+1},a_{2k+2})\in A_n.$$
So in this case, you have that the $S_n$-conjugacy class of $\sigma$ splits in $A_n$, and yet $\sigma$ is $A_n$-conjugate to its inverse.
We can construct other examples by taking $\sigma$ to be a product of disjoint cycles  of pairwise distinct odd lengths in which the  number of lengths that are congruent  to $3$ modulo $4$ is even. So for example, $(1,2,3)(4,5,6,7,8,9,10)$ has an $S_n$ conjugacy class that splits, but you can conjugate it into its inverse in $A_n$ for any $n\geq 10$ by taking $\rho=(2,3)(5,10)(6,9)(7,8)$.
